# looping values through a function to create env variables

Tags: r, function, for-loop

Is there a way to write this so that the params are passed through the function in order to loop through each time?

```
monthget <- function(x,y,z){
  db_grab %>%
    filter(month(ImportDate) == y & year(ImportDate) == z) %>% 
    assign(x ,., env = .GlobalEnv )
}

obj_names = c('oct','nov','dec','jan','feb','mar')
months = c(10,11,12,1,2,3)
years = c(2022,2023)

combined = list(obj_names, months, years)

for (i in 1:length(combined)) {
  monthget(obj_names[i], months[i], years[i])
}
```

Running

```
monthget('oct', 10, 2022)
```

will assign an environment variable named oct and I would need to do this each time for the following months and years. Trying to pass this through automatically in a single chunk

Comment: Please avoid POLLUTING the global environment. Consider storing your variables in a container most preferable a LIST. if they have a similar structure, you can store them in a grouped dataframe. It is easier to loop/deal with a container than having a bunch of several tens of thousands of variabels in the global environment

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this using `mapply` function, which applies a function in parallel over two or more vectors:

```
obj_names = c('oct','nov','dec','jan','feb','mar')
months = c(10,11,12,1,2,3)
years = c(2022,2022,2022,2023,2023,2023) # I've adjusted the years to match your months

mapply(monthget, obj_names, months, years)
```

`mapply` applies the function `monthget` to the first element of `obj_names`, the first element of `months`, and the first element of `years`, and then to the second elements, and so on.

In your current approach, I wonder why you're assigning some variables to Global environment. Just because you have two years and more months? I would suggest having equal length vectors (created using `rep`).